# Azure Pipeline Yaml pipeline

Tags: azure-devops

I have two different yaml pipelines one for production and one for development.
Dev:

```yaml
trigger:
  batch: True
  branches:
    include:
      - Development
  paths:
    include: 
    - Azure/Payload/Development/Payload.json
```

Production:

```yaml
trigger:
  batch: True
  paths:
    include: 
    - Azure/Payload/Prod/Payload.json
```

When I committed the development branch file both the Prod and dev and pipelines are executing. But it is executing successfully and on another side, if I trigger prod only the prod pipeline alone got triggered.
I am not sure why and how this happens.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in the second you are missing branch filter like on the first one

```yaml
 branches:
    include:
      - Development
```

So if your branch is `Production` please add branch filter:

```yaml
 branches:
    include:
      - Production
```